# Python - Weird behaviour in array re-ordering

Tags: python, arrays

I am trying to rearrange some arrays but it doesn't seem to always work properly:

```
# Works fine
arr = np.array([2,3,1])    
idx1 = np.array([1,0,2])
arr[idx1]
>> array([3, 2, 1])

# Doesn't work
arr = np.array([2,3,1])
idx2 = np.array([2,0,1])
arr[idx2]
>> array([1, 2, 3]) # Should have been [3,1,2]
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: No, it should be `[1,2,3]`. `1` is in pos 2, `2` is in pos 0, `3` is in pos 1. Another way to look at this: indexing on `[1,0,2]` yields `[3,2,1]`; why wouldn't reversing the indices reverse the output array?

Comment: To get [3,1,2] you need `idx2 = np.array([1,2,0])`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**index** rebuilds your array with the **index array**. The **index array** contains a list of positions (indexes) of elements in the original array.

> Numpy arrays may be indexed with other arrays (or any other sequence-
>   like object that can be converted to an array, such as lists, with the
>   exception of tuples; see the end of this document for why this is).
>   The use of index arrays ranges from simple, straightforward cases to
>   complex, hard-to-understand cases. For all cases of index arrays, what
>   is returned is a copy of the original data, not a view as one gets for
>   slices.
>
> Index arrays must be of integer type. Each value in the array
>   indicates which value in the array to use in place of the index.

In your case:

```
arr = np.array([2,3,1])
idx2 = np.array([2,0,1])
```

**index** `[2, 0, 1]` means `[third element, first element, second element]`

With `arr[idx2]` you get `[1, 2, 3]`. It's right.

Example: **index** with second and third element

```
>>> arr[np.array([1,2])]
array([3, 1])
```

Comment: Thank you, I get it now. For some reason (stupidity) I thought it worked by assigning new positions to the respective elements.